# How to add Array and copy to inside

Tags: php

I have an array.

```
$arr = Array ( 
[0] => Array ( ["PID"] => "1" ["QTY"] => "2" ) 
[1] => Array ( ["PID"] => "2" ["QTY"] => "2" ) 
[2] => Array ( ["PID"] => "3" ["QTY"] => "3" ) 
[3] => Array ( ["PID"] => "4" ["QTY"] => "1" ) 
[4] => Array ( ["PID"] => "5" ["QTY"] => "1" ) 
)
```

Need out put like below add `-` to duplicate array have 2 qty or more.

```
$arr =  Array ( 
[0] => Array ( ["PID"] => "1" ["QTY"] => "2" ) .
[1] => Array ( ["PID"] => "1" ["QTY"] => "-" ) 
[2] => Array ( ["PID"] => "2" ["QTY"] => "2" ) 
[3] => Array ( ["PID"] => "2" ["QTY"] => "-" ) 
[4] => Array ( ["PID"] => "3" ["QTY"] => "3" ) 
[5] => Array ( ["PID"] => "3" ["QTY"] => "-" ) 
[6] => Array ( ["PID"] => "3" ["QTY"] => "-" ) 
[7] => Array ( ["PID"] => "4" ["QTY"] => "1" ) 
[8] => Array ( ["PID"] => "5" ["QTY"] => "1" ) 
)
```

Thank for any help.

Comment: make it more sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over each element in your original array, adding elements to the output array according to the quantity in the original array:

```
$out = array();
foreach ($arr as $a) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $a['QTY']; $i++) {
        $out[] = array('PID' => $a['PID'], 'QTY' => $i == 1 ? $a['QTY'] : '-');
    }
}
print_r($out);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/G54KC)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be need this function - array_splice . You can insert element to array at any index that you want .